# Trying to use newly created resource in Delphi without success

Tags: delphi, resources

I got into strange behavior in Delphi.

I need to apply correct logo.jpg in a runtime.
So I created the list in logo.rc file and produced logo.RES file out of it.

```
Image1 RCDATA "Img\logo1.jpg"
Image2 RCDATA "Img\logo2.jpg"
```

Now, I want to display the correct image.
In MyForm I pass the correct resource name:

```
MyStream := TResourseStream.Create(HInstance, 'Image1', RT_RCDATA);
try
 MyImage.Picture.LoadFromStream(MyStream);
finally
 MyStream.Free;
```

Now I want to add directive to use this newly created resource. I do that in .dpr file, just under the regular directive:

```
{$R *.RES}
{$R Logo.RES}
```

But when I run the project, I got an image that once was in use. Looks like Delphi somehow "remembers" it from somewhere and I cannot figure out where from. I don't see any references to that old file in project's options.

I tried to delete project.RES/project.dres files and recompile to let it create the file again.

I tried to delete the first directive. Then in run time I do get the proper image, but the Access violation in KernekBase.dll is thrown.

I tried even to change the name of my newly Logo.RES to the projectName.RES.

And I'm still getting the old image.
I'm using Delphi 10.2.

Maybe someone has some insights on how to tackle this problem? Thank you

Comment: Add a pre-build event in the project options where you compile the .rc file to a .res file. Delphi fails on properly detect when to do this automatically!

Comment: If you put the directive into the DPR in the form {$R Logo.RES Logo.RC } it should be properly handled by Delphi when you make a _build_ instead of just a _compile_.

Comment: אל @DelphiCoder I compiled .rc file to a .res file using cmd brcc32

Comment: to @UweRaabe I tried that. If I use the syntax you wrote, it tells me that resource Image1 not found. Anfd if I do it this way {$R 'Logo.RES' 'Logo.RC' }, there is no errors but I still get the old file.

Comment: I don't see how can I edit my question, but I discovered one more thing. If I turn off Manifest file autogenerate to none, then I get the proper file. So this is somehow connected

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the `Edit` button beneath the tags of your question.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the quotes in my example.

Comment: @LenaGavrilov The only way I can think of for an "old" image to be remembered is if you had previously loaded an image into a `TImage` in the Form Designer and it got saved into the Form's DFM. `Picture.LoadFromStream()` would override any existing image, so it makes me wonder whether or not the `MyImage` you are loading into in code is actually the same `TImage` object that is holding the "old" image? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue in action.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end it worked. I was playing around a lot.
Looks like something with Delphi.
May be it is not the perfect answer but...  I'll put my way around.

I noticed that if I disable creating manifest file automatically, I do get the right image.
So I created manifest file manually, basically copying what Delphi would produce by itself and tried to eliminate entries. After I eliminated **assemblyIdentity** I again got the proper file.
When after this I enabled Delphi back to create manifest file automatically, it worked!